# High CPU usage by Django App

Tags: django

I've created a pretty simple Django app which somewhat produces a high CPU load: rendering a simple generic view with a list of simple models (20 of them) and 5-6 SQL queries per page produce an apache process which loads CPU by 30% - 50%. While memory usage is pretty ok (30MB), CPU load is not ok to my understanding and this is not because of apache/wsgi settings or something, the same CPU load happens when I run the app via runserver.

Since, I'm new to Django I wanted to ask:
1) Are these 30-50% figures an usual thing for a Django app? (Django 1.4, ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7.3)
2) How do I profile CPU load? I used a profile middleware from here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/186/ but it shows only ms numbers not CPU load numbers and there was nothing special, so how do I identify what eats up so much CPU power?

Comment: How are you measuring the 30-50% CPU usage? What are you using to run the load?

Comment: I use **top** in Linux and watch %CPU column for an apache2 process which appears while I'm browsing the app (or while I'm bombarding it via **ab**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPU usage itself doesn't tell how efficient your app is. More important metric to measure the performance is how many requests/second your app can process. The kind of processor your machine has naturally also has a huge effect on the results.

I suggest you to run `ab` with multiple concurrent requests and compare the requests/second number to some benchmarks (there should be many around the net). ab will try to test the maximum throughput, so it's natural that one of the resources will be fully utilized (bottleneck), usually this is disk-io. As an example if you happen to get CPU usage close to 100% it may mean you are wasting CPU somewhere (reqs/second is low) or you that have optimized disk-io well (reqs/s high).

Comment: My app gives 25 req/s on a 2GB Linode VPS. Now I'm curious, how to check if this is ok? Are any ideal numbers available or something to compare with?

Comment: @Timus83 There isn't clear answer if that is ok. It depends on so many things. You should read more about Django performance and some benchmarks available to get a ballpark number what is acceptable for you. I'm sure there are many people benchmarking Django apps on EC2 ([here](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg94216.html) is one). If under load your CPU is not close to 100% you know that you should concentrate on optimizing database access (caching for example).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the %CPU column is not very accurate. I certainly see spikes of 50%-100% CPU all of the time.. it does not indicate how long a cpu is being used, just that we hit that value at that specific moment. These would fall into min / max figures, not your average cpu usage.

Another important piece: say you have 4 cores as I do which means the 30-50% figure on `top` is out of a maximum of 400%. 50% on top means 50% of one core, 12.5% on all four, etc.

You can press 1 in top to see individual core cpu figures.

Comment: hm, thanks for a tip. I'm a bit curious why do these spikes arise at all? For example, if I run rails based app like redmine, spikes go 10% at max and this is a very complex app written on Ruby. My app, from the other side, is simple and is written on a more performant Python, so I'm somewhat surprised to see such spikes and want to find out their reason.